# Word online not sending et parameter when user accesses add-in as trial

Tags: ms-word, office365, add-in, office-addins, office-js

We are having a problem with our add-in, which is a Word only task pane add-in with add-in commands. The add-in has passed the review and is published in the store. We can successfully sign up for a trial in the Office store and get the instructions on how to activate the add-in a document.

The add-in can be added to a document, at least to the point of showing the add-in command menu and button. However, when we try to start the add-in (as in opening it's task pane window by clicking the button in the Office ribbon) the add-in refuses to start due to not receiving the "et" parameter. We are at least two persons who can reproduce the symptom.

We have tested to add trials of another totaly unrelated add-in, which oddly enough does get the "et" parameter passed on and therefore works as expected. This problem really has us stumped; we have no clue what we can do to make Office actually send us the parameter?

Edit 2016-11-24: The add-in is ReadSpeaker Text to Speech for Office 365, can be found in Office store at https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380516.

Also, by saying "not receiving the et parameter" above I mean that the actual parameter is indeed in the query string, but it is empty. So it looks like:

[...]/home.php?et=&_host_Info=[...]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the add-in refuses to start due to not receiving the "et" parameter".  Is it not starting due to your own logic, which requires the parameter, or do you mean that the framework itself is unable to start the addin?

Comment: i think he is referring to the entitlement token. Markus, Can you share what  add-in are you talking about ? probably we can try to repro here. thanks!

Comment: Sorry guys, I missed your comments since SO didn't notify me about them. I've tried to clarify regarding the et (entitlement token) parameter in the original question and specified which add-in the question concerns.

Comment: @Markus, @MichaelZlatkovsky - I can confirm that this is also a problem for my Excel Add-In. I just tried creating a trial with a new/separate account from any of my accounts. The `et` parameter is empty when accessing the add-in from in Excel Online but it **is not empty** in the Excel client. I also did this for both personal Excel online and Office 365 Excel online with the same results -- no `et` param. I have confirmed this with diagnostic logging on the server which tells me if `et` param has a value or not.

Comment: See Humberto's reply at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997956/in-excel-online-the-framework-is-not-passing-the-et-license-token-parameter-f#comment69303523_41029937

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved (validation with "ReadSpeaker"). Please try it again.

Comment: We have tested on our side by adding the add-in to a Microsoft live account as a trial and it now seems like it works. Thanks!