# In Excel Online, the framework is not passing the "et" license token parameter for paid and trial Add-ins

Tags: office-js

I don't know if this is related to recent Excel online query string param discussions so I'm starting a different thread.

The `et` param **is** being passed by the Excel client but **not** in Excel online. I have tried both paid and trial (within trial period) Add-ins.

It may be related to this thread also
[Word online not sending et parameter when user accesses add-in as trial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651490/word-online-not-sending-et-parameter-when-user-accesses-add-in-as-trial)

Comment: Let me pass this on to the team.  IIRC, there had been some subtleties in the past with how identity is handled, esp. WRT to personal (Microsoft Account) identifies vs Work (O365 Business) identities.  We'll have someone get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug of Addin Commands and has been fixed (validation with "Compare and Merge" and "Range Tracker"). Please try it again.

Comment: Yes, this has been fixed and I also validated it with my add-ins.  Thanks a lot! Jim

Comment: @miaofei-wang, I'm running into this issue now with my add-in as well. The et token is passed successfully from Excel desktop client, but not from Excel online. This applies to both trial and paid add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reaching out. Our team investigated and looks like we have a bug, and no, it isn't related to that other thread. We will follow up.

Comment: Thanks Humberto. Look forward to your follow up.

Comment: So yes we have confirmed that this is an issue on our end and turns out it 'might' be related to that other thread. The team is actively working on the issue, I don't have an ETA to share though. As I know more I'll let you know more. Thank you

Comment: It also occurs periodically for users of my Outlook add-in

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue with outlook online, it seems that the value of the StoreType value within OsfControl is always hardcoded to "exchange" in https://r1.res.office365.com/owa/prem/16.1569.8.2186260/scripts/microsoft.owa.extensibilitynext.js
 which leads to undefined _omnexEntitlment when the etoken is retrieved it's always been retrieved with the initial empty string value.

```js
 getEToken: function() {
            return this._omexEntitlement ? this._omexEntitlement.etoken : this._etoken
        },
```