# Outlook for Windows not passing "et" parameter/license to Outlook Add-In

Tags: outlook, office365, add-in, office-js, officedev

We developed an add-in for Outlook which is published in the store already. It has paid and trial versions. License checking in the add-in works fine if the add-in is used from a browser, Outlook for Mac. But if it is Outlook for Windows or outlook.live.com (versions where "add-in commands" feature is enabled and add-in is opened in a side bar) then no license information is passed.

Example:

- This correct URL is navigated from Outlook Web and Outlook Mac:

  `https://serverurl?et=%3cr+v%3d%221%22%3e%3ct..............`
- This is how the URL looks like for Outlook for Windows:

  `https://serverurl?_host_Info=Outlook|Win32|16.01|en-US`

So, since Outlook for Windows does not supply license information we have to refuse add-in access for our clients on Outlook for Windows.

I found related questions for [Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997956/in-excel-online-the-framework-is-not-passing-the-et-license-token-parameter-f) and [Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651490/word-online-not-sending-et-parameter-when-user-accesses-add-in-as-trial), but none of them was answered yet. The problem is that it is Outlook that needs to send the data, so we can do nothing in our code to troubleshoot.

Guys, any ideas where the problem is or what to check in the manifest?

Here is the link to the add-in listing in the Office store ([TextMiner](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380592)) if it may help to answer.

Comment: Microsoft enabled "add-in command" in Outlook Web as well, so license check is not working there as well